# Do Gigabit ethernet single-mode fiber network adapters exist?

Tags: linux, nic, fiber, gigabit-ethernet, 10gbethernet

I am attempting to set up a server with a total of four single-mode fiber ports - two need to be at least 1Gb and two must be 10Gb. I have found a variety of 10Gb single-mode fiber network adapters (for example the [Intel X520-LR1](http://ark.intel.com/products/41164/Intel-Ethernet-Converged-Network-Adapter-X520-LR1) and the [QLogic 3242-LR](http://www.qlogic.com/Products/adapters/Pages/IntelligentEthernetAdapters.aspx)), but no 1Gb single-mode fiber adapters. Do they exist?

I will only have two PCI-E x8 slots (unless I am forced to get a larger server), so both network adapters would need to have two ports.

Comment: [They](http://www.gigabit-server-adapter.com/china-single_mode_fiber_sfp_slot_dual_port_lc_fiber_optic_cable_optical_ethernet_converter-367785.html) do [exist](http://www.interfacemasters.com/products/32285.html).

Comment: Thanks @DavidSchwartz. I think I just figured out what I was missing... if a network adapter has SFP ports, I can install a single-mode fiber SFP transceiver (or multi-mode, or copper) and essentially turn that network adapter into a single-mode fiber adapter. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.